# I'm calling a table-valued function within a stored procedure, but I get an error : Invalid object name 'FnFoBoSec'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE BorBsec
    (@sec NVARCHAR(30))
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM FnFoBoSec(@sec)
```

When executing this procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure BorBsec, Line 9
>   Invalid object name 'FnFoBoSec'

Comment: Function calls should always be used **with** the schema information, e.h. `FROM dbo.FnFoBoSec(@sec)` - add the `dbo.` prefix

Comment: @marc_s: I don't think it's a "*should* be used", but "**have** to be used with schema"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: good point, yes, it's not optional, or a best practice - it's a **must** - thanks for clarifying

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks . Im just new to this T-SQL , At beginner lever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** use the schema prefix when calling a **function** in T-SQL.

Try to change your code to this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE BorBsec
    (@sec NVARCHAR(30))
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.FnFoBoSec(@sec)
         *****
```

Of course, if your function should have been created in a *different schema* (other than the default `dbo` schema), then you must replace that with the actual schema prefix.